# Как получить микшер браузера (сменить громкость)?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, winapi, аудио

Есть wpf xaml, в котором есть элемент WebBrowser и слайдер громкости. На слайдере ивент. Надо сменить громкость окна через слайдер, когда запущен youtube.Я пытался через winmm.dll (WaveOutSetVolume) - не работает после запуска в браузере контента. user32.dll sendmessagew - меняет главную громкость. Как получить доступ к громкости или микшера окна?

```
private void ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    // Calculate the volume that's being set
    double newVolume = ushort.MaxValue * e.NewValue / 10.0;

    uint v = ((uint)newVolume) & 0xffff;
    uint vAll = v | (v << 16);

    // Set the volume
    int retVal = NativeMethods.WaveOutSetVolume(IntPtr.Zero, vAll);
}

static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "waveOutSetVolume")]
    public static extern int WaveOutSetVolume(IntPtr hwo, uint dwVolume);
}
```

Comment: Как вариант, можно воспользоваться `InvokeScript()` и `document.getElementById("movie_player").setVolume(100)` (вместе с `document.getElementById("movie_player").getVolume()`) можно будет синхронизировать оба слайдера, YouTube’вый и WPF’ный.

Comment: Ваш вопрос решен?

Comment: Пока еще нет...

Comment: Ответ не подошел?

Comment: В моей ситуации он не является решением проблемы, так как на этапе добавления элементов отображения ломается и у меня есть не только ютуб. Я искал решения по плоскости WinApi или чего-то стандартного с шарпу.

Answer (score 2):

Для получения регулятора громкости определенного процесса можно взять реализацию метода GetVolumeObject из [данного ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/903387/240512). Тогда код изменения громкости будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
ISimpleAudioVolume volume;

void Initialize() //вызвать после начала воспроизведения первого видео со звуком
{
    Process pr=Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    using(pr)
    {
        volume = GetVolumeObject(pr.Id);
    }
}

private void ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
{
    // Calculate the volume that's being set
    float newVolume = (float)e.NewValue;

    // Set the volume
    Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
    int res = volume.SetMasterVolume(newVolume, ref guid);
    if (res != 0) throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(res);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну, как-то так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


  namespace VolumeOff
  {
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct WAVEFORMATEX
    {
        public ushort wFormatTag;
        public ushort nChannels;
        public uint nSamplesPerSec;
        public uint nAvgBytesPerSec;
        public ushort nBlockAlign;
        public ushort wBitsPerSample;
        public ushort cbSize;
    }


   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
    public const uint WAVE_MAPPER = unchecked((uint)(-1));
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern uint waveOutOpen(ref uint hWaveOut, uint uDeviceID, ref WAVEFORMATEX lpFormat, uint dwCallback, uint dwInstance, uint dwFlags);

    [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern uint waveOutGetVolume(uint hwo, ref uint dwVolume);

    [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
    public static extern int waveOutSetVolume(uint uDeviceID, uint dwVolume);

    [DllImport("winmm.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern uint waveOutClose(uint hwo);

    [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "RtlZeroMemory", SetLastError = false)]
    static extern void ZeroMemory(ref WAVEFORMATEX dest, int size);


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uint volume = 0;
        unsafe
        {
            uint hWO = 0;
            WAVEFORMATEX waveF = new WAVEFORMATEX();

            ZeroMemory(ref waveF, sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX));
            waveOutOpen(ref hWO, WAVE_MAPPER, ref waveF, 0, 0, 0);
            waveOutGetVolume(hWO, ref volume);
            waveOutClose(hWO);
        }
        textBox1.Text = volume.ToString();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            uint hWO = 0;
            WAVEFORMATEX waveF = new WAVEFORMATEX();

            ZeroMemory(ref waveF, sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX));
            waveOutOpen(ref hWO, WAVE_MAPPER, ref waveF, 0, 0, 0);
            waveOutSetVolume(hWO, Convert.ToUInt32(textBox1.Text.ToString()));
            waveOutClose(hWO);
        }
     }
  }
}
```