# Изменение громкости другого приложения

Tags: c#, windows, аудио

Нашел такой код:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SetAppVolumne
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string app = "Mozilla Firefox";

            foreach (string name in EnumerateApplications())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("name:" + name);
                if (name == app)
                {
                    // display mute state & volume level (% of master)
                    Console.WriteLine("Mute:" + GetApplicationMute(app));
                    Console.WriteLine("Volume:" + GetApplicationVolume(app));

                    // mute the application
                    SetApplicationMute(app, true);

                    // set the volume to half of master volume (50%)
                    SetApplicationVolume(app, 50);
                }
            }
        }

        public static float? GetApplicationVolume(string name)
        {
            ISimpleAudioVolume volume = GetVolumeObject(name);
            if (volume == null)
                return null;

            float level;
            volume.GetMasterVolume(out level);
            return level * 100;
        }

        public static bool? GetApplicationMute(string name)
        {
            ISimpleAudioVolume volume = GetVolumeObject(name);
            if (volume == null)
                return null;

            bool mute;
            volume.GetMute(out mute);
            return mute;
        }

        public static void SetApplicationVolume(string name, float level)
        {
            ISimpleAudioVolume volume = GetVolumeObject(name);
            if (volume == null)
                return;

            Guid guid = Guid.Empty;
            volume.SetMasterVolume(level / 100, ref guid);
        }

        public static void SetApplicationMute(string name, bool mute)
        {
            ISimpleAudioVolume volume = GetVolumeObject(name);
            if (volume == null)
                return;

            Guid guid = Guid.Empty;
            volume.SetMute(mute, ref guid);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateApplications()
        {
            // get the speakers (1st render + multimedia) device
            IMMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)(new MMDeviceEnumerator());
            IMMDevice speakers;
            deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia, out speakers);

            // activate the session manager. we need the enumerator
            Guid IID_IAudioSessionManager2 = typeof(IAudioSessionManager2).GUID;
            object o;
            speakers.Activate(ref IID_IAudioSessionManager2, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out o);
            IAudioSessionManager2 mgr = (IAudioSessionManager2)o;

            // enumerate sessions for on this device
            IAudioSessionEnumerator sessionEnumerator;
            mgr.GetSessionEnumerator(out sessionEnumerator);
            int count;
            sessionEnumerator.GetCount(out count);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                IAudioSessionControl ctl;
                sessionEnumerator.GetSession(i, out ctl);
                string dn;
                ctl.GetDisplayName(out dn);
                yield return dn;
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ctl);
            }
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sessionEnumerator);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mgr);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(speakers);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(deviceEnumerator);
        }

        private static ISimpleAudioVolume GetVolumeObject(string name)
        {
            // get the speakers (1st render + multimedia) device
            IMMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)(new MMDeviceEnumerator());
            IMMDevice speakers;
            deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia, out speakers);

            // activate the session manager. we need the enumerator
            Guid IID_IAudioSessionManager2 = typeof(IAudioSessionManager2).GUID;
            object o;
            speakers.Activate(ref IID_IAudioSessionManager2, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out o);
            IAudioSessionManager2 mgr = (IAudioSessionManager2)o;

            // enumerate sessions for on this device
            IAudioSessionEnumerator sessionEnumerator;
            mgr.GetSessionEnumerator(out sessionEnumerator);
            int count;
            sessionEnumerator.GetCount(out count);

            // search for an audio session with the required name
            // NOTE: we could also use the process id instead of the app name (with IAudioSessionControl2)
            ISimpleAudioVolume volumeControl = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                IAudioSessionControl ctl;
                sessionEnumerator.GetSession(i, out ctl);
                string dn;
                ctl.GetDisplayName(out dn);
                if (string.Compare(name, dn, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
                {
                    volumeControl = ctl as ISimpleAudioVolume;
                    break;
                }
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ctl);
            }
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sessionEnumerator);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mgr);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(speakers);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(deviceEnumerator);
            return volumeControl;
        }
    }

    [ComImport]
    [Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E")]
    internal class MMDeviceEnumerator
    {
    }

    internal enum EDataFlow
    {
        eRender,
        eCapture,
        eAll,
        EDataFlow_enum_count
    }

    internal enum ERole
    {
        eConsole,
        eMultimedia,
        eCommunications,
        ERole_enum_count
    }

    [Guid("A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IMMDeviceEnumerator
    {
        int NotImpl1();

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow dataFlow, ERole role, out IMMDevice ppDevice);

        // the rest is not implemented
    }

    [Guid("D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IMMDevice
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int Activate(ref Guid iid, int dwClsCtx, IntPtr pActivationParams, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object ppInterface);

        // the rest is not implemented
    }

    [Guid("77AA99A0-1BD6-484F-8BC7-2C654C9A9B6F"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IAudioSessionManager2
    {
        int NotImpl1();
        int NotImpl2();

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetSessionEnumerator(out IAudioSessionEnumerator SessionEnum);

        // the rest is not implemented
    }

    [Guid("E2F5BB11-0570-40CA-ACDD-3AA01277DEE8"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IAudioSessionEnumerator
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetCount(out int SessionCount);

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetSession(int SessionCount, out IAudioSessionControl Session);
    }

    [Guid("F4B1A599-7266-4319-A8CA-E70ACB11E8CD"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IAudioSessionControl
    {
        int NotImpl1();

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetDisplayName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string pRetVal);

        // the rest is not implemented
    }

    [Guid("87CE5498-68D6-44E5-9215-6DA47EF883D8"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface ISimpleAudioVolume
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetMasterVolume(float fLevel, ref Guid EventContext);

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetMasterVolume(out float pfLevel);

        [PreserveSig]
        int SetMute(bool bMute, ref Guid EventContext);

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetMute(out bool pbMute);
    }
}
```

Но его выполнение мне выдаёт следующее: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что нужно исправить?

P.S. использую Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У WASAPI-сессий имя часто пустое или бессмысленное. Для идентификации сессий конкретного приложения лучше использовать ID процесса:

```
private static ISimpleAudioVolume GetVolumeObject(int pid)
{
    // get the speakers (1st render + multimedia) device
    IMMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)(new MMDeviceEnumerator());
    IMMDevice speakers;
    deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia, out speakers);

    // activate the session manager. we need the enumerator
    Guid IID_IAudioSessionManager2 = typeof(IAudioSessionManager2).GUID;
    object o;
    speakers.Activate(ref IID_IAudioSessionManager2, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out o);
    IAudioSessionManager2 mgr = (IAudioSessionManager2)o;

    // enumerate sessions for on this device
    IAudioSessionEnumerator sessionEnumerator;
    mgr.GetSessionEnumerator(out sessionEnumerator);
    int count;
    sessionEnumerator.GetCount(out count);

    uint val;

    ISimpleAudioVolume volumeControl = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        IAudioSessionControl ctl;
        sessionEnumerator.GetSession(i, out ctl);

        IAudioSessionControl2 ctl2 = (IAudioSessionControl2)ctl;
        ctl2.GetProcessId(out val);

        if (val == pid)
        {
            volumeControl = ctl as ISimpleAudioVolume;
            break;
        }
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ctl);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ctl2);
    }
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sessionEnumerator);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mgr);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(speakers);
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(deviceEnumerator);
    return volumeControl;
}
```

Интерфейс IAudioSessionControl2:

```
[Guid("bfb7ff88-7239-4fc9-8fa2-07c950be9c6d"),
InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface IAudioSessionControl2
{
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetState(out object state);
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetDisplayName(out IntPtr name);
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetDisplayName(string value, Guid EventContext);
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetIconPath(out IntPtr Path);
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetIconPath(string Value, Guid EventContext);
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetGroupingParam(out Guid GroupingParam);
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetGroupingParam(Guid Override, Guid Eventcontext);
    [PreserveSig]
    int RegisterAudioSessionNotification(object NewNotifications);
    [PreserveSig]
    int UnregisterAudioSessionNotification(object NewNotifications);

    [PreserveSig]
    int GetSessionIdentifier(out IntPtr retVal);
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetSessionInstanceIdentifier(out IntPtr retVal);
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetProcessId(out UInt32 retvVal);
    [PreserveSig]
    int IsSystemSoundsSession();
    [PreserveSig]
    int SetDuckingPreference(bool optOut);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорректировав изначальный код согласно ответу, всё равно получал ошибку при приведении MMDeviceEnumerator к IMMDeviceEnumerator. Смог инициализировать IMMDeviceEnumerator другим способом, вот код всего приложения:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SetAppVolumne
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int app = 2880;


                    Console.WriteLine("Mute:" + GetApplicationMute(app));
                    Console.WriteLine("Volume:" + GetApplicationVolume(app));

                    // mute the application
                    SetApplicationMute(app, true);

                    // set the volume to half of master volume (50%)
                    SetApplicationVolume(app, 50);

        }

        public static float? GetApplicationVolume(int name)
        {
            ISimpleAudioVolume volume = GetVolumeObject(name);
            if (volume == null)
                return null;

            float level;
            volume.GetMasterVolume(out level);
            return level * 100;
        }

        public static bool? GetApplicationMute(int name)
        {
            ISimpleAudioVolume volume = GetVolumeObject(name);
            if (volume == null)
                return null;

            bool mute;
            volume.GetMute(out mute);
            return mute;
        }

        public static void SetApplicationVolume(int name, float level)
        {
            ISimpleAudioVolume volume = GetVolumeObject(name);
            if (volume == null)
                return;

            Guid guid = Guid.Empty;
            volume.SetMasterVolume(level / 100, ref guid);
        }

        public static void SetApplicationMute(int name, bool mute)
        {
            ISimpleAudioVolume volume = GetVolumeObject(name);
            if (volume == null)
                return;

            Guid guid = Guid.Empty;
            volume.SetMute(mute, ref guid);
        }


        private static ISimpleAudioVolume GetVolumeObject(int pid)
        {
            // get the speakers (1st render + multimedia) device
            IMMDeviceEnumerator deviceEnumerator = (IMMDeviceEnumerator)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromCLSID(new Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E")));
            IMMDevice speakers;
            deviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow.eRender, ERole.eMultimedia, out speakers);

            // activate the session manager. we need the enumerator
            Guid IID_IAudioSessionManager2 = typeof(IAudioSessionManager2).GUID;
            object o;
            speakers.Activate(ref IID_IAudioSessionManager2, 0, IntPtr.Zero, out o);
            IAudioSessionManager2 mgr = (IAudioSessionManager2)o;

            // enumerate sessions for on this device
            IAudioSessionEnumerator sessionEnumerator;
            mgr.GetSessionEnumerator(out sessionEnumerator);
            int count;
            sessionEnumerator.GetCount(out count);

            uint val;

            ISimpleAudioVolume volumeControl = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                IAudioSessionControl ctl;
                sessionEnumerator.GetSession(i, out ctl);

                IAudioSessionControl2 ctl2 = (IAudioSessionControl2)ctl;
                ctl2.GetProcessId(out val);

                if (val == pid)
                {
                    volumeControl = ctl as ISimpleAudioVolume;
                    break;
                }
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ctl);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ctl2);
            }
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sessionEnumerator);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(mgr);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(speakers);
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(deviceEnumerator);
            return volumeControl;
        }
    }

    [ComImport]
    [Guid("bfb7ff88-7239-4fc9-8fa2-07c950be9c6d"),
    InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    interface IAudioSessionControl2
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetState(out object state);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetDisplayName(out IntPtr name);
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetDisplayName(string value, Guid EventContext);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetIconPath(out IntPtr Path);
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetIconPath(string Value, Guid EventContext);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetGroupingParam(out Guid GroupingParam);
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetGroupingParam(Guid Override, Guid Eventcontext);
        [PreserveSig]
        int RegisterAudioSessionNotification(object NewNotifications);
        [PreserveSig]
        int UnregisterAudioSessionNotification(object NewNotifications);

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetSessionIdentifier(out IntPtr retVal);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetSessionInstanceIdentifier(out IntPtr retVal);
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetProcessId(out UInt32 retvVal);
        [PreserveSig]
        int IsSystemSoundsSession();
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetDuckingPreference(bool optOut);
    }
    [Guid("BCDE0395-E52F-467C-8E3D-C4579291692E")]
    internal class MMDeviceEnumerator
    {
    }

    internal enum EDataFlow
    {
        eRender,
        eCapture,
        eAll,
        EDataFlow_enum_count
    }

    internal enum ERole
    {
        eConsole,
        eMultimedia,
        eCommunications,
        ERole_enum_count
    }

    [Guid("A95664D2-9614-4F35-A746-DE8DB63617E6"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IMMDeviceEnumerator
    {
        int NotImpl1();

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow dataFlow, ERole role, out IMMDevice ppDevice);

        // the rest is not implemented
    }

    [Guid("D666063F-1587-4E43-81F1-B948E807363F"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IMMDevice
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int Activate(ref Guid iid, int dwClsCtx, IntPtr pActivationParams, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] out object ppInterface);

        // the rest is not implemented
    }

    [Guid("77AA99A0-1BD6-484F-8BC7-2C654C9A9B6F"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IAudioSessionManager2
    {
        int NotImpl1();
        int NotImpl2();

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetSessionEnumerator(out IAudioSessionEnumerator SessionEnum);

        // the rest is not implemented
    }

    [Guid("E2F5BB11-0570-40CA-ACDD-3AA01277DEE8"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IAudioSessionEnumerator
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int GetCount(out int SessionCount);

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetSession(int SessionCount, out IAudioSessionControl Session);
    }

    [Guid("F4B1A599-7266-4319-A8CA-E70ACB11E8CD"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface IAudioSessionControl
    {
        int NotImpl1();

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetDisplayName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] out string pRetVal);

        // the rest is not implemented
    }

    [Guid("87CE5498-68D6-44E5-9215-6DA47EF883D8"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
    internal interface ISimpleAudioVolume
    {
        [PreserveSig]
        int SetMasterVolume(float fLevel, ref Guid EventContext);

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetMasterVolume(out float pfLevel);

        [PreserveSig]
        int SetMute(bool bMute, ref Guid EventContext);

        [PreserveSig]
        int GetMute(out bool pbMute);
    }
}
```

ID приложения можно найти в разделе "Подробности" диспетчера задач.