# C# системный микшер

Tags: c#, windows, аудио

Всем доброго времени суток, у меня вопрос. Почему приведенный ответ к данному вопросу https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306048/controlling-volume-mixer
может работать только с Mozilla Firefox, когда указываю другой браузер смотря в Микшер громкости системы ввожу название точно такое же, но оно просто не определяет.

Comment: В коде ответа есть вывод всех определенных устройств: `Console.WriteLine("name:" + name);` что пишет у вас? Может вы неправильно строку названия др.браузера пишите?

Comment: Потому что сессии WASAPI не обязаны иметь осмысленное имя. См. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/862954/240512

Comment: С Google Chrome всё равно не работает, но да ладно, спасибо.